# C++ std::remainder() function returning (incorrect) negative values for a pair of positive numbers

Tags: c++, math, std, cmath

I'm trying to obtain the remainder of two float numbers in C++ for some calculations and I found out that the built in std::remainder() function doesn't always return what I expect to.

For a concrete example, `std::remainder(683.242, 27.8576183)` returns `-13.1985`, instead of ~`14.66`. I realized that `-13.1985` is what you would have to add to 27... to obtain the correct remainder, which makes me suspect that -13... is the expected result and I'm missing something about what std::remainder() really does.

I'd be thankful if someone could tell me why std::remainder() returns negative values, or point me to some function / library that I can actually use to obtain 'normal' remainders from decimal numbers.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder

Comment: Found the answer immediately after but thank you both. That definitely answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was short, but I found out that I'm, indeed, not supposed to use std::remainder() to get the remainder. The function that actually returns the mathematical 'normal' remainder is std::fmod() because reasons.

The reason std::remainder() doesn't work is because it rounds the quotient towards the nearest integer, as explained [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/). This also explains why the negative remainders I were getting were the difference between the divisor and the expected remainder.

Answer (score 1):

The floating-point remainder of the division operation x/y calculated by `std::remainder(x,y)` is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where the value n is the integral value nearest the exact value x/y. If `|n-x/y| = 0.5 (precisely)`, the value `n` is then chosen to be even.

So the returned value is not guaranteed to have the same sign as x.

If it rounds one way you get a positive number, if you round another you can get a negative one. Consider using `std::fmod(...)`